# window.open cannot set popup name

Tags: javascript, html

I use the following code to open a popup.

```
var correctiveActionReportURL = top.CONTEXT_PATH + "secure/houseKeepingCorective" 
+"!viewReport.action?"+params; 
window.open(correctiveActionReportURL, "Corrective Action", "",false);
```

The window opens fine but the window name doesn't change according to the value I pass.

Is this method deprecated or am I doing anything wrong.

Comment: Sorry I'll edit the question! I want to set the name!

Comment: A window name should not contain spaces.

Comment: I checked with no spaces but it doesn't appear. It shows the action url in the name.

Comment: Sounds like you are still confusing the window name and the title of the document …

Comment: yeah... I got the idea now. what I'm looking to set is the window title. I set the title using the following code :

var win = window.open();
win.document.title = "Title";

But when the document finishes loading the title is replaced by the URL.

Comment: If you are in charge of the content in the window you are opening then why not use the html `<title>` in the subsequent document?